# Periodic boundary conditions in a 2D array

Tags: python, physics, numerical-methods, differential-equations, pde

I need to implement the following boundary conditions in my Python code   f(0, x) = f(-1, x) = 0  and f(y, 0) = f(y, N) (periodic in the second index).

My code doesn't seem to work. F is a numerical solution of a hyperbolic partial differential equation

```
for j in range(0, m-1):
        for i in range(0, n-1):
            
            f[0, i] = 0
            f[-1, i] = 0
            
            f[j, 0] = f[j, -1]
            f[j, -1] = f[j, 1]
```

Comment: what is `N` in the question ?  also what happens for overlaps where f(0,0) = f(0, N=0) ? this is a conflict (2 values).

Comment: N is the length of the x domain, from 0 to N.

Comment: so `f(y, N=0)` has a value, say `F` where `F  !=  0`.  which means that `f(0,0) = 0 ` would conflict with `f(0,0) !=  0`.  Explain how ?

Comment: I guess I could use f(1, x) = f(-2, x) = 0 and f(y, 0) = f(y, N) to fix that, right?

Comment: well, in general, the code would need to ensure that `y != first variables` and `N=second variable` otherwise the same value would be created twice (overwritten).